# Trigger created with compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11gr2

I am trying to create a trigger that increases the discnt of a customer by  .04 every time that customer  places an order. Next I need to insert a new order  in the orders table.

**The following is the Customers table:**

```
CID  CNAME         CITY                     DISCNT
c001 Tiptop        Duluth                       10
c002 Basics        California                   12
c003 7/11          California                    8
c004 ACME          Duluth                        8
c006 ACME          Kyoto                         0
c007 Goldberg      NYC                          15
```

**The following is the orders table:**

```
 ORDNO MON CID  AID PID        QTY    DOLLARS
  1011 jan c001 a01 p01       1000        450
  1012 jan c001 a01 p01       1000        450
  1019 feb c001 a02 p02        400        180
  1017 feb c001 a06 p03      95959        540
  1018 feb c001 a03 p04        600        540
  1023 mar c001 a04 p05        500        450
  1022 mar c001 a05 p06        400        720
  1025 apr c001 a05 p07        800        720
  1013 jan c002 a03 p03       1000        880
  1026 may c002 a05 p03        800        704
  1015 jan c003 a03 p05       1200       1104
  1014 jan c003 a03 p05       1200       1104
  1021 feb c004 a06 p01       1000        460
  1016 jan c006 a01 p01       1000        500
  1020 feb c006 a03 p07        600        600
  1024 mar c006 a06 p01        800        400
```

**The trigger I have created is:**

```
create or replace trigger UpdateDiscnt
after insert or update on orders   
  for each row
  begin 
     update customers set  discnt = 0.4 + :old.discnt where 
     customers.cid=:new.cid;
  end;
   /
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Maybe removing  `:` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: MYSQL or sqlserver? - there is no create or replace trigger (you need to Drop then create)  in mysql and no update or insert (choose one at a time).

Comment: @McNets I updated the trigger based on you comments to the following: create trigger UpdateeDiscount
after insert on orders   
  for each row
  begin 
     insert into customers set discnt = 0.4 + :discnt where 
     customers.cid=:new.cid;
  end;
/ ==> the error messages I get are the following:  2/6      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/28     PL/SQL: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
2/47     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'DISCNT'

Comment: @P.Salmon I am using SQL command line (black background) - mysql

Comment: @Sam you have posted Oracle syntax, and an Oracle PL/SQL error — but you say you are connected to a MySQL database? Post the result of this query: `SELECT * FROM v$version;`

Comment: @Jack Douglas its Oracle DB! Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Answer (score 0):

The error is an oracle error and there is no discnt in the order table so any version of old.discnt is incorrect.

try

```
create or replace trigger UpdateDiscnt
after insert or update on orders   
  for each row
  begin 
     update customers set  discnt = 0.4 + discnt 
     where  customers.cid= :new.cid;         

  end;
   /
```

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon it worked!! Now I'm trying to insert a row in the orders table as follows: 
insert into orders (ordno,month,cid,aid,pid,qty,dollars)
values (1030,’jan’,’003’,’a06’,’p01’,100,500.00); 
This is the result I get: 
 insert into orders (ordno,month,cid,aid,pid,qty,dollars)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.UPDATE_DISCNT' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: the trigger update_discnt differs in name from the trigger updatediscnt, I suggest it's an old failed attempt to create, drop it if you agree.